# Replace capture group content in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

In my JavaScript code I have a regular expression with capture groups (that is configured by library user) and a source string which matches this regular expression. The regular expression matches whole string (i.e. it has `^` and `$` characters at its start and end).

A silly example:

```
var regex = /^([a-zA-Z]{2})-([0-9]{3})_.*$/;
var sourceStr = "ab-123_foo";
```

I want to reassemble the source string, replacing values in the capture groups and leaving the rest of the string intact. Note that, while this example has most of the "rest of the string" at its end, it actually may be anywhere else.

For example:

```
var replacements = [ "ZX", "321" ];
var expectedString = "ZX-321_foo";
```

Is there a way to do this in JavaScript?

NB: The regular expression is configured by the library user via the legacy API. I can not ask user to provide a second regular expression to solve this problem.

Comment: But can you ask your user to modify the regex? If so, you could enclose the rest of the string with another pair of parenthesis and get it for free.

Comment: I can modify the regex myself programmatically to that effect, I think

Answer (score 3):

Without changing the regex the best I can think of is a callback that replaces the matches

```
sourceStr = sourceStr.replace(regex, function(match, $1, $2, offset, str) {
    return str.replace($1, replacements[0]).replace($2, replacements[1]);
});
```

That's not a very good solution, as it would fail on something like

```
var sourceStr = "ab_ab-123_foo";
```

as it would replace the first `ab` instead of the matched one etc. but works for the given example and any string that doesn't repeat the matched characters

```js
var regex = /^([a-zA-Z]{2})-([0-9]{3})_.*$/;
var sourceStr = "ab-123_foo";

var replacements = [ "ZX", "321" ];

sourceStr = sourceStr.replace(regex, function(match, $1, $2, offset, str) {
    return str.replace($1, replacements[0]).replace($2, replacements[1]);
});

document.body.innerHTML = sourceStr;
```

Comment: Looks like one can transform `/^([a-zA-Z]{2})-([0-9]{3})_.*$/` to `/^([a-zA-Z]{2})(-)([0-9]{3})(_.*)$/` programmatically, no?

Comment: Not quite sure how you'd do that, but I guess it involves turning the regex into a string and doing replacements on that string and passing it to the RegExp constructor, and while it may be possible, I'm not sure it's a very good idea ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/source

Why would this be a bad idea?

Comment: I don't know, it just seemed a little hinky to me to get the string value of a regular expression and doing replacements and then passing it back the the RegExp constructor. As I said, it's possible, and it will most likely work, and that's the important part, I personally just don't like it very much,

Answer (score 1):

I think this is close. It satisfies the two test cases but I'm unsure about leading and trailing groupings.

```
function replacer (regex, sourceStr, replacements) {

  // Make a new regex that adds groups to ungrouped items.

    var groupAll = "";
    var lastIndex = 0;
    var src = regex.source;
    var reGroup=/\(.*?\)/g;
    var match;
    while(match = reGroup.exec(src)){
        groupAll += "(" + src.substring(lastIndex, match.index) + ")";
        groupAll += match[0];
        lastIndex = match.index + match[0].length;
    }

    var reGroupAll = new RegExp(groupAll);

  // Replace the original groupings with the replacements
  // and append what was previously ungrouped.

    var rep = sourceStr.replace(reGroupAll, function(){

        // (match, $1, $2, ..., index, source)
      var len = arguments.length - 2;
      var ret = "";

      for (var i = 1,j=0; i < len; i+=2,j++) {
        ret += arguments[i];
        ret += replacements[j];
      }
      return ret;
    });

    return rep;
}


var regex = /^([a-zA-Z]{2})-([0-9]{3})_.*$/;
var sourceStr = "ab-123_foo";
var replacements = [ "ZX", "321" ];
var expectedString = "ZX-321_foo";

var replaced = replacer(regex, sourceStr, replacements);
console.log(replaced);
console.log(replaced === expectedString);

regex = /^.*_([a-zA-Z]{2})-([0-9]{3})$/;
sourceStr = "ab_ab-123";
expectedString = "ab_ZX-321";

var replaced = replacer(regex, sourceStr, replacements);
console.log(replaced);
console.log(replaced === expectedString);
```

Output:

```
ZX-321_foo
true
ab_ZX-321
true
```

Comment: I don't know the structure, the RegExp is configured by the library user.

Comment: @AlexanderGladysh I adjusted the answer for an unknown regex.

Comment: Will it work, say, for string `ab_ab-123` and regex `/^.*_([a-zA-Z]{2})-([0-9]{3})$/`?

Comment: @AlexanderGladysh The ab_ab-123 test had failed so I changed the replacer to satisfy that test case as well.